# Why Datatable header and footer not get displayed properly initially?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have configured datatable as below:

```
function BindDataTable(targetGrid) {
        var sortableGrid = $(targetGrid).attr('id');
        var DT = $('#' + sortableGrid).dataTable({
            "fnInitComplete": function () {
                $('#' + sortableGrid + ' thead > tr').removeClass().addClass("HeaderGridView2").css('cursor', 'pointer');
                $('#' + sortableGrid + ' tfoot > tr').removeClass().addClass("FooterGridView2");
            },
            "bPaginate": false,
            "bLengthChange": false,
            "bFilter": false,
            "bSort": true,
            scrollY: '500px',
            "bInfo": false,
            "bScrollCollapse": true,
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            "asStripClasses": null, //To remove "odd"/"event" zebra classes
            "fnDrawCallback": function () {
                $('#' + sortableGrid + ' tr').removeClass();
                $('#' + sortableGrid + ' tr:even').addClass("RowGridView2 even");
                $('#' + sortableGrid + ' tr:odd').addClass("AlternatingRowGridView2 odd");
                $('#' + sortableGrid + ' thead > tr').removeClass().addClass("HeaderGridView2").css('cursor', 'pointer');
                $('#' + sortableGrid + ' tfoot > tr').removeClass().addClass("FooterGridView2");
            }
        });

    }
```

But when the datatable gets binded and displayed first time it does not gets display properly as header and footer not set as per column width. After click on any column to sort table it gets displayed as expected with property header and footer as in below screen. Why does this happens?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### CAUSE

Most likely your table is hidden initially such as being in a modal window, inactive tab or other hidden element.

#### SOLUTION

You need to handle event when table is shown and call [`columns().adjust()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust%28%29) API method. This will recalculate the column widths after a change in the display.

```js
$('#'+initId).DataTable()
    .columns.adjust();
```

See [`columns().adjust()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/columns.adjust%28%29) API methods for more information.

#### LINKS

See [jQuery DataTables – Column width issues with Bootstrap tabs](http://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-column-width-issues-with-bootstrap-tabs) for solutions to the most common problems with columns in jQuery DataTables when table is initially hidden.

Comment: I have that table in ajax:ModalPopupExtender panel. Don't know when to bind datatable